# NoMethod error for select statement

Tags: ruby

```
class Filter

  def filterMethod(arr)

    new_array1 = puts arr.select.each_with_index { |str, i| i.odd? }
    yield
    new_array2 = puts arr.select.each_with_index { |str, i| i.even? }
    yield
    new_array3 = puts arr.reject! {|x| x < '3'}
    yield
    new_array4 = puts arr.reject! {|x| x < '4'}
    yield
 end
end

puts "Enter a list of numbers"
list = Array.new

list = gets.chomp
F= Filter.new
F.filterMethod(list) {puts "--------"}
#list = Array.new
```

I am not able to access array in class.How to get array value in method. Its showing following error:

> "`filterMethod': private method 'select' called for nil:NilClass
>   (NoMethodError)"

Comment: Your question seem to be distorted. Are you pasting the actual post and error?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets see:

```
list = Array.new
# => []  # An Array
```

Now,

```
list = gets.chomp
asd
# => "asd" # A String

F= Filter.new
F.filterMethod(list) # You are passing a String
```

In `Filter#filterMethod`

```
# arr is supposed to be an Array
arr.select.each_with_index { |str, i| i.odd? } # list is passed as argument which is a String
```

Hence:

> NoMethodError: private method `select' called for "asd":String

You can convert string into array by splitting it, either using [`.chars`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-chars) or [`.split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-split) (*both serves different purpose*, **read docs**). Here:

```
list = gets.chomp
12345
# => "12345"  # A String
list = list.chars
# => ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"] # An Array
```

or to get Integer Array (as you are doing Integer operations in your method):

```
list = list.chars.map(&:to_i)
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: What needs to be done so that arr is array in filterMethod?

Comment: that depends. How do you want to pass the array? Can you post a sample `arr` ?

Comment: I am passing array from console like 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: @PoojaKulkarni Whatever you type in the console, it's a string. You have to manually convert it to an array. Try `list = gets.split(/\W/)`

Comment: @PoojaKulkarni I have updated my answer based on your latest comment. Please check

Comment: Thank you shivam. Got expected result :)

Answer (score 0):

```
list = gets.chomp
```

returns a string. You seem to be expecting an array, so something extra needs to be here. eg:

```
list = gets.chomp.split
```

This is still a list of str though, so you may need another step if you want ints

```
 list = gets.chomp.split.map{|x|x.to_i}
```